# NodeJs get-Pixels isolate Red Channel

Tags: node.js, image, post, pixel

So I'm trying to make a score calculation for my game, and have made a simple API that will take in the image and respond with the score. To optimise it, I'm only interested in the Red Channel of the texture, but I don't know how I would achieve this. I have this :

```
// Calculates the Score
function calculateScore(pixels){
    var score = 0;
    // Iterate through the Red Channel
    for (var r = 0; r < pixels.length; r++){
        score += pixels[r];
    }

    return score;

};
```

I'm unsure on how I'd go about isolating just a single channel

Answer (score 0):

```
// Calculates the Score
function calculateScore(pixels){
    var score = 0;
    // Iterate through the Red Channel
    for (var r = 0; r < pixels.length; r++){
        if(r%4==0){
            score += pixels[r];
        }
    }

    return score;
```

};

Not my proudest moment xD